# How to change Facebook iOS SDK's done button color when login?

Tags: customization, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

[image]

My app use white UITabBarItem text color and orange UINavigationBar BarTintColor, when click the Login button added from Facebook SDK, it will popup a webview for login.

but the topbar background color always light gray, if I change the UITabBarItem color, other view will all changed, How can I only custom the button color in Facebook login view or change the navbar background color?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. 
If anywhere inside your app has this line, please comment it out.

```
self.window.tintColor = white;
```